# Restrict environment variables to command when cross compiling Golang program on Windows

Tags: batch-file, go, environment-variables, cross-compiling

I'm cross compiling Golang programs on Windows for Linux, using:

```
go build -o myprog.bin myprog.go
```

To do so I have to set the environment variable GOOS=linux.  As I'm also compiling some programs for windows, when I'm done with the cross compile I have to reset GOOS=windows.  So I have a batch file as follows:

```
set GOOS=linux
go build -o myprog.bin myprog.go
set GOOS=windows
```

If I happen to be compiling two programs for each Linux and Windows simultaneously, the windows program may get compiled for Linux.  Is there a way to limit the scope of an environment variable to a command on windows, or to override it for a command? eg

```
go build -o myprog.bin myprog.go -GOOS linux
```

I know goxc provides this, but can go build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build upon Greg's answer which explains that changes using the [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command are limited to the process, if you want to limit scope of environment variable changes within  a process, use the [`setlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) and [`endlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) commands.  This allows you to isolate variables within a single command process.

```
setlocal
set GOOS=linux
go build -o myprog.bin myprog.go
endlocal
:: GOOS will now equal what it was before being set within the scope
```

Comment: This is what I was getting at, although I was hoping I could just pass the os to the go build command in a one liner.  `setlocal && set GOROOT=C:\Go\Test\ && echo %GOROOT% && endlocal` isn't run sequentially.  I guess goxc is the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are local to the process in which they are set (and descendants of that process). So when you do `set GOOS=linux`, the change happens only within that command processor and doesn't affect any other existing processes. New processes started from within that command processor inherit the current values of its environment variables.

So in short, your solution of `set GOOS=linux` followed by `set GOOS=windows` will work fine, and there is no risk of that interfering with other simultaneous builds.

Comment: If I set GOROOT=x at the command prompt, then at the start of a script set GOROOT=y, when the script exits echo %GOROOT% displays y, which suggests to me that based on your answer GOOS and GOROOT are different kinds of environment variables.  Is that right?

Comment: Setting an environment variable within a script affects the value of the environment variable for that command prompt after the script exits (this is different behaviour from Unix-like systems).

Comment: Ok, that might be worse.  The scripts don't have to be simultaneous, just run from the same prompt.  So they're not limited to the command unless the command is in a the only thing run from that prompt, or in a batch  file run from windows.  Sounds like the way to go would be  set GOROOT=y && go build... && set GOROOT=x but it's 2am here, I'll pick this up later.  Thanks.

Comment: To solve that, your build scripts should not rely on the value of any pre-existing environment variables that might have been changed by a previous run of a script.